# What is this plant with two types of leaves?

Tags: identification

Found this in my yard. One type of leaf is needle-like and about 2 1/2" long with vertical veining. The other is like a mimosa or honeylocust with compound bi-pinate leaves. They're growing from the same stalk!! [image: mart]

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of terms that will be useful to you in your researches here: dimorphism and phyllode. Dimorphism is simply the occurrence of more than one leaf type on a single plant, which is more common than you might think; take junipers for example where there can be sharp juvenile leaves and blunt mature leaves on one bush. Your example is related to the [phyllode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phyllode) and is common on Acacia species.

[image]

The image above is a smaller version of an image from Wikimedia commons of Acacia koa, a tree from Hawaii. You don't say where you are from or what sort of plant it occurs on, but these would be common in places like Australia.